# plant height $h(t)$ increases at constant rate $k$%. if in $100n$ hours height is doubled, prove $k=\frac{1}{n}\ln2$

Tags: derivatives

plant height $h(t)$ increases at constant rate $k$%. if in $100n$ hours plant height is doubled, prove $k=\frac{1}{n}\ln2$

**My Try**

I used compound interest theory to calculate this;
$2h=h(1+\frac{k}{100})^{100n}$
But I cannot get the required answer. What is my mistake? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Compound interest isn't $2h = h(1 + \frac k{100})^{100n}$.  That is interest calculated 100 times a year.  Compound interest is interest calculated every possible instant, an infinite number of times a year.  $2h = 2*\lim_{m\to \infty}(1 + \frac km)^{mn} = h*e^n$.

Comment: @HardikKalra that's not relevant.

Comment: You need he formula that *continuous* growth at $k\%$ is calculated by $h(t) = h(0)* e^{\frac k{100}t}$.  As it is doubling it doesn't matter what $h(0)$ is.  You know $h(100n) = 2h(0)$ and $h(100n) = h(0) e^{\frac k{100}100n}$ so $2= e^{\frac k{100}100n}$.  No need to know what $h(0)$ is.

Comment: Aah shit! I misread the question. It is just a simple differential equation that I had to solve. I’m really sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the plant grew in spurts once a year you would calculate

$h(t) = h(1 + .01*k)^t$.

If the plant grew in spurts $m$ times a year you would calculate

$h(t) = h(1+ .01*\frac km)^{mt}$.

But if the plant grew continuously it you would calculate

$h(t) = h\lim_{m\to \infty} (1+ .01*\frac km)^{mt}=h\lim_{m\to \infty}[ (1 + \frac 1m)^m]^{0.01* kt} = he^{0.01*kt}$.

So $2h = h(100n) = h e^{0.01*k*100n} = he^{nk}$

So $2 = e^{nk}$ so

$\ln 2 = nk$ and

$k = \frac {\ln 2} n$

====

Euler's number is often (not always) defined to be $\lim_{n\to \infty} (1 + \frac 1n)^n$.  This is useful for continuous growth question.

If something is growing at a constant rate of $r$ (per time unit) and but growing continually then the compounded growth after time $t$ will be $\lim_{n\to \infty} (1+ \frac rn)^{nt} = \lim_{n\to \infty} [(1+\frac 1n)^n]^{rt} = e^{rt}$.

This is based on $\lim_{n\to \infty} (1 + \frac an)^n =\lim_{n\to \infty}(1 + \frac 1n)^{an} = e^a$.

But you asked in a comment why we can move the $a$ for $(1+\frac an)^n$ to the exponent $(1 + \frac 1n)^{an}$?

Well.....

$\lim_{n\to \infty} (1 + \frac an)^n=$

$\lim_{n\to \infty} (1 + \frac 1{\frac na})^{a\cdot \frac na}$.

Let's replace then notation of $\frac na$ with $m$ so

$\lim_{n\to \infty} (1 + \frac 1{\frac na})^{a\cdot \frac na}=$

$\lim_{am \to \infty}(1 + \frac 1m)^{am}$.

Now $am\to \infty$ as $m\to \infty$ so

$\lim_{am\to \infty}(1 + \frac 1m)^{am} =$

$\lim_{m \to \infty}(1 + \frac 1m)^{am} =$

$\lim_{m\to \infty}[(1 + \frac 1m)^m]^a =$

$e^a$.

Comment: Really appreciated the help. Could you kindly tell how you took 0.01k out to the power coefficient ? Its not clear to me.